# How to make a field array reference for a class in another constructor's class

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, constructor, reference

Now write a class car (derived from thread)! The constructor passes a reference to a field of `Ampel`, which reference is stored in a corresponding attribute of the car class

How do I do that how can I make a class named `Car` with a constructor in this class and I have to make a reference of a field of class `Ampel` and put it in an attribute of the class `Car`? Can anyone help and the reference of the field needs to be in the constructor

```
  private String Ampelfarbe ;
    public Ampel() {  
       }
public String schalteRot() {
    this.Ampelfarbe = "rot"  ;
    return this.Ampelfarbe;
    }
public String schalteGruen() {
    this.Ampelfarbe = "grun";
    return this.Ampelfarbe;
}
public void passieren() {
    while (this.Ampelfarbe == "rot") {
        try {
            wait();
        }catch  (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    if ( this.Ampelfarbe == "grun") {
        notify();
        return ;
    }

    }
```

Comment: What do you have problems with? How to make a class? How to make a constructor in a class? "The constructor passes **a reference** to a field of Ampel" - a reference to what?

Comment: my problem is how i implement the both methods schaltegrun and schalterot to change the color of ampel in the new array that i have in the contructor of the car class 
and i need to have different colors of Ampels in the array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712883/traffic-light-code-exercice-problem-how-to-solve-it?noredirect=1#comment103719019_58712883

this is the exercice that i tried to do u can check it out if u want and try it

Comment: You really got an assignment to develop multi-threaded code when you are missing even the simplest fundamental things? I suggest starting with [the tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/tutorialLearningPaths.html#newtojava) and prepare for a long night...

Comment: this is not the finished code i still did not finish it and i know what ur taking about the start methode in main